# making 3d plots with functions that modify copies of variables in the global scope

Tags: r, 3d, vectorization

I'm trying to make some 3d surface plots in `r` and I'm getting strange behavior when I try to use the `outer` function. `outer` takes a user-defined function that yields z-axis values given any (x,y)-pair. How do I write a function that

- is safely vectorized, and
- also modify copies of variables in the global scope correctly.

For example, this code

```
x <- c(4,5,6)
my_f <- function(first, second){
  x[1] <- first
  sum(x) + second
}
a <- b <- c(1,2,3)
c <- outer(a,b, my_f)
row.names(c) <- b
colnames(c) <- a
```

produces

```
   1  2  3
1 13 14 15
2 13 14 15
3 13 14 15
```

when I am expecting

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   14   15
[2,]   14   15   16
[3,]   15   16   17
```

At least it tips me off and gives me a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In x[1] <- first :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works pretty well:

```
x <- c(4,5,6)
my_f <- function(first, second){
  x[1] <- first
  sum(x) + second
}
a <- b <- c(1,2,3)
args <- expand.grid(a,b)
z <- mapply(my_f, args[,1], args[,2])
dim(z) <- c(length(a), length(b))
```